# hook_modules_enabled called before hook_menu

Tags: 7, hooks

(Note: the code and module names have been simplified for demonstration)

I have a number of custom modules in a Drupal 7 site. One of the modules (a 'base' module enabled during site installation) creates a custom menu (operations-menu) along with a hook (hook_operations_menu()) for customizing the menu. Other custom modules (I'll refer to them as implementing modules) with a need to add menu links into the operations-menu can simply implement hook_operations_menu() and return the appropriate menu item definitions.

Example:
Assuming my base module is called 'base' and my implementing module is called 'implements'.

**base.module**

```
/**
* Implements hook_modules_enabled()
*/
function base_modules_enabled($modules) {
  $links = [];
  foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $module_links = module_invoke($module, 'operations_menu');
    if(is_array($module_links))
      $links = array_merge($links, $module_links);
  }
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    menu_link_save($link);
  }
}
```

**implementing.module**

```
/**
* Implements hook_operations_menu()
*/
function implementing_operations_menu() {
  $links = [];

  // Define menu links here

  return $links;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function implementing_menu(){
  $items = [];

  // Define menu callbacks, etc.

  return $items;
}
```

This strategy works well to maintain a modularized custom menu with one exception. For some reason, when enabling the implementing module, `base_modules_enabled()` is called before `implementing_menu()`. This is a problem since some menu links defined in `implementing_operations_menu()` depend on routing established in `implementing_menu()`.

[I've checked the source code](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_enable/7.x), and `module_enable()` invokes `hook_modules_enabled()` at the very end. I don't understand how `hook_menu()` is getting called after `hook_modules_enabled()` and not before.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's the solution. Hopefully it helps save someone else some time. As it turns out, `hook_menu()` is not invoked during module enabling. As such, I had to force a menu rebuild which invokes `hook_menu()` and ensures all the proper routes exist prior to building my menu links.

**base.module>**

```
/**
* Implements hook_modules_enabled()
*/
function base_modules_enabled($modules) {
  menu_rebuild(); // <--- Added this line to force hook_menu() to be called first
  $links = [];
  foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $module_links = module_invoke($module, 'operations_menu');
    if(is_array($module_links))
      $links = array_merge($links, $module_links);
  }
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    menu_link_save($link);
  }
}
```